# OpenCV imshow Error

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am doing some image processing using OpenCV C++. However, when I pass an image to a function in a class I get this error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(...)`. Code:

```
Mat image = img.clone();
if(!image.data){
   cout << "No image found!" << endl;
   exit(-1);
}
imshow("running image",image); waitKey();  // ERROR-> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

Now before passing the image to this function in `Main` I print the image and its perfectly alright and as expected. Also I placed a condition to `exit(-1)` incase of no image data.

I placed a breakpoint and check and the image contains data in this function but I can't figure out what the error causes the program to crash in `Highgui` of `OpenCV`, i.e `imshow` function.

Any help is highly appreciated.

I found the error.

**ERROR**

*When I was initialising a pointer to variable to modify the image, I was initialising the pointing using malloc(Sizeof(float) * NUM) and accidentally, the NUM macro was initialise to type float and therefore it created and error since number of chances of memory cannot be allocated in floats but int.*

Comment: Thats weird. Your code chunk worked fine for me at different implementations (as surely expected). Anyways, could you please elaborate the context? Additionally, are you sure you didn't miss any image processing at this chunk?

Comment: @kazarey I tried to debug and check the content of Mat in main and in this function and its total equivalent. However, error only occurs when I use the #include<highgui> of opencv.

Comment: @user1965914 may there is any error in `linking configuration` and better to do all the step like load the image and check whether its loading or not by showing your image using `imshow` . because there is no error in your code